# Problemas com CRUD em linguagem C

Tags: c, crud

Fala pessoal, estou precisando fazer um CRUD com estas características ai e não estou conseguindo, podem me dar uma luz no fim do túnel ai? agradeço desde já.

Meu problema nao está na armazenagem, e sim na ordem, não sei o que esta errado, se alguem puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Faça um algoritmo em linguagem C que emule as características de um player de músicas sendo executado em modo texto, via prompt de comando.

1. Deve-se criar uma playlist das músicas utilizando uma lista encadeada. A lista encadeada poderá ser simples ou dupla, circular ou não circular. Fica a critério do aluno decidir.
2. Deve-se armazenar o nome de cada música, do artista/banda e a duração da faixa. Para o armazenamento utilize uma estrutura heterogênea de dados.
3. Para inserção dos dados, você pode criar uma leitura dos dados através de um menu na tela ou já deixá-los armazenados em um arquivo texto no seu computador e só carregar este arquivo ao executar o programa. Ou ambas soluções. Decida também como você irá implementar a inserção (no início, no fim ou no meio da lista encadeada);
4. Deve existir um menu na tela. Este menu deve permitir a inserção de novas músicas (caso optado pela inserção manual de dados), deve ter a opção de listar todas as músicas da playlist (listagem de uma lista encadeada) na tela e encerrar o programa;

este é o meu código :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Play_list
{  
    char musica[30];
    char Artista[30];
    float duracao;
    struct Play_list *proximo;
};
    struct Play_list * cria(void)
    {  
        return NULL;
    }

struct Play_list * insere(struct Play_list * l, char * musica, char * Artista, float duracao) { 
    struct Play_list * novo = (struct Play_list *) malloc(sizeof(struct Play_list));
    strcpy(novo->musica, musica);
    strcpy(novo->Artista, Artista);
    novo->duracao = duracao;
    novo->proximo = l;
    return novo;

}
void imprime(struct Play_list * l)

{
    struct Play_list * p;
    for(p = l; p != NULL; p = p->proximo)

    {
        printf("Musica : %s \n", p->musica);
        printf("ARTISTA : %s \n", p->Artista);
        printf("Duracao : %.2f \n", p->duracao);
}
}

int busca(struct Play_list * l, char * musica)
{
    struct Play_list * p;
    int i = 1;
    for (p = l; p != NULL; p = p->proximo)

    {
        if (strcmp(musica, p->musica) == 0)

        {

            printf("Musica: %s %s %s \n", p->musica);
            return i;

        }   i++;

    }  return 0;

}

    main()

    {
 char grupo[30], artista[30];
 float duracao;
 struct Play_list * l;
 char resp = 's';
 char procura[30];

 printf(" ************************ \n");
 printf("|    PLAYER              |\n");
 printf("|          DE            |\n");
 printf("|             MUSICAS    |\n");
 printf("|                        |\n");
 printf(" ************************ \n");
 printf("\n\n");


 l = cria();
 while (resp != 'n')
 {
     printf("Qual eh a Musica? \n");
     scanf("%[^\n]", grupo);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("De quem eh a musica? \n");
     scanf("%[^\n]", artista);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Qual eh o duracao? \n");
     scanf("%f", &duracao);
     fflush(stdin);
     l = insere(l, grupo, artista, duracao);
     printf("Continua? s/n \n");
     scanf("%c", &resp);
     fflush(stdin);

 }

 imprime(l);
 printf("Qual musica quer ouvir? \n");
 scanf_s("%s", procura);
 printf("Esta musica esta na posicao %d da play list\n", busca(l, procura));
 system("pause");
 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como podem ver, não esta rodando na ordem correta e se eu continuar a colocar os dados, ele é interrompido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem pode me dar uma força? nao consigo achar o erro.

Comment: editei o título, porque não existe "linguagem C/C++"...o que existe é a linguagem C, e a linguagem C++

Comment: não seria uma possível duplicata, pois meu problema não está na armazenagem dos dados e sim na ordem em que está saindo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando `setbuf(stdin, NULL);` para limpar os buffs entre os scans, porque já vi muitas pessoas reclamando da `fflush()` por não funcionar corretamente, em meus projetos sempre uso a setbuf quando tenho o mesmo tipo de problema.